# What happens if I use a callback method from an activity that is about to finish?

Tags: java, android, http

I am doing an HTTP request from my `InitActivity`:

```
private void initUserById(int challengerId) {
        Call call = StaticGlobalContainer.api.getUser(challengerId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                StaticGlobalContainer.currentUser = response.body();
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    // 200
                    // User object returned from server
                    Log.i("Getting user by id", ACTIVITY_TAG+"_Success");
                } else {
                    // 404 or the response cannot be converted to User.
                    Log.e("Getting user by id", ACTIVITY_TAG+"_Error:" + response.errorBody());
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.i("HttpRequest - Get user", ACTIVITY_TAG+"_Failure");
            }
        });
    }
```

This activity ends as soon as user presses a button to go to the next activity:

```
setUserIdBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                StaticGlobalContainer.CURRENT_USER_ID = userIdEditText.getText().toString();
                initUserById(Integer.parseInt(StaticGlobalContainer.CURRENT_USER_ID));
                startActivity(new Intent(InitActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });
```

What happens, if there is a slight delay on the server and it won't respond before user presses the button?

Since activity has already ended, I would expect an exception, but isn't it handled somehow? Like that the activity wouldn't be disposed until callback has been made?

**EDIT:**

After some thinking, I assume that such callbacks as described above are one of the reason they invented `ProgressBars`, is that right?

Comment: it depends on what you do in the callback

Comment: HTTP Get request with a Retrofit. I would populate a public static object `CurrentUser` on the callback.